# I am looking for a list of the biggest european hospitals in Europe by number of beds

Tags: medical, europe

I am looking for the 10 biggest European hospitals by number of bed. I can't find this data anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This page shows a ranking of hospitals by size: http://hospitals.webometrics.info/en/europe?sort=asc&order=Size though I have no idea how reliable it is.

---

This page shows the number of hospital beds per country: http://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?DataSetCode=HEALTH_STAT# (under 'health care resources' -> 'hospital beds')

---

Some wikipedia pages (in native languages) seem to have the number of hospital beds per hospital, though this is not a complete picture:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_hospitals_in_Europe

Some wikipedia pages with hospital beds:

- https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijst_van_Belgische_ziekenhuizen
- https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijst_van_Nederlandse_ziekenhuizen
- https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_over_norske_sykehus